# Singular custom taxonomy label

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy called "Artists" which has the taxonomy singular name set to "Artist".

If a post only has 1 artist I would like the label to be "Artist" instead of "Artists".

How could I achieve this? My current code is below. Thanks!

```
<?php  
        $taxo_text = "";  
        $artists = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'artists', "<div class='grid_2 details'>
     <ul class='credits'> <li class='smallunderline'>Artists</li><li> ", '</li><li>', '</li></ul></div>' );  

        if ( '' != $artists ) {  
            $taxo_text .= $artists;  
        }  

        if ( '' != $taxo_text ) {  

        echo $taxo_text;  

        } // endif  

        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`get_the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) returns an array of the terms, and is used by [`get_the_term_list()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list) to build the links. You can query it and count the number of returned terms. Since the result is cached, it won't query the database again.

```
$artists = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'artists' );
if ( $artists ) {
    $artistsLabel = ( 1 == count( $artists ) ? 'Artist' : 'Artists' );
    $taxo_text .= get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'artists', "<div class='grid_2 details'>
 <ul class='credits'> <li class='smallunderline'>{$artistsLabel}</li><li> ", '</li><li>', '</li></ul></div>' ); 
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this already be covered if the taxonomy is registered with all the appropriate labels, namingly a singular and plural label?

Comment: @t31os: You would expect so, but [`get_the_term_list()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.2/wp-includes/category-template.php#L932) is not very advanced and appends just the `$before` parameter, it makes no attempt to create a sensible default value.